# 整数の和が0の場合の2乗の和

Tags: python, python3

入力した整数の合計数の和が0になったら各整数を2乗し、その和を出力したいと思っています。

例えば以下の通り入力した場合、-3の時点で合計数の和は0となるので1、2、-3のそれぞれの2乗の和を足した14を出力します。

**例1:**

```
1
2
-3
4
6
-9
```

でも、もし例えば次のように最初に0がある場合は0を出力します。

**例2:**

```
0
1
2
-3
4
6
-9
```

そこで、このようなコードを書きました。

```
res = []
while True:
    num = int(input())
    if sum(res) != 0:
        res.append(num)
    else:
        break
squares = int(res) ** 2
print(squares)
```

その結果、このようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
    squares = int(res) ** 2
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

そこで8行目を次のように書き換えたところ

```
   squares = res ** 2
```

このようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

どのように改善すれば良いでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

やろうとされていることはだいたい理解できましたが、いくつか別々の問題があるので、順に直していきましょう。

```py
res = []
while True:
    num = int(input())
    if sum(res) != 0:
        res.append(num)
    else:
        break
```

まず上記の部分ですが、 while ループの初回実行時では `res` 変数のリスト（配列）は空っぽです。
このため、 `sum(res)` は 必ず 0 になります。
ゆえに、 `input()` で入力された数値にかかわらず、 `break` に到達してしまいます。

ここでは、以下のように `sum` 関数で総和を計算する**前**に、 `res` リストに入力した数値を追加するのが良いでしょう。

```py
res = []
while True:
    num = int(input())
    res.append(num)
    if sum(res) == 0:
        break
```

これで、 意図したとおり 1, 2, -3 と入力されたときにループを抜けるようになりました。

---

しかし、これでもまだ以下のエラーは続きます。

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

これは、 `res` 変数が、数値ではなく、リスト（配列）なので、一般的な算術計算ができないためです。

> 1、2、-3のそれぞれの2乗の和を足した

と書かれているので、ちゃんと `res` リスト内の**それぞれ**の要素について、2乗してやる必要があります。

書き方は色々ありますが、

```py
squares = 0
for n in res:
    squares += n ** 2
print(squares)
```

とか、 [ジェネレータ式](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) という仕組みを使って、以下のように1行で書くことも可能です。

```
squares = sum(n ** 2 for n in res)
print(squares)
```

これで、期待した 14 が出力されます。

Comment: python を勉強される上では、是非以下のような記事を参考に、「デバッグ（トレース実行）」機能を使って、一行一行どのように動くのかたどりながら勉強する事をオススメしますよ。

https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/2104/23/news022.html

Answer (score 2):

`res` はリストなので list comprehension(リスト内包表記)を使います。

```py
squares = sum(x*x for x in res)
```

その他に numpy の dot product(ドット積:[numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot)) を使うと同じ結果が得られます。

```py
import numpy as np

squares = np.dot(res, res)
```